# Get rid of stray dog's urination

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I am venkat, from Chennai,India, staying in a Apartment. We are facing a problem with our neighbhour pet dog which urniates in our car&bike parking area. I have requested the owner of the don in this regards but thet least bother about it. Is there any way to stop this? Pls advice.

Comment: Nothing that doesn't involve chasing the dog or the owner, no. The dog is marking it's territory so other dogs know it is in the area. Unless you move the territory line somehow (for example but putting up a fence) of the dog's owner does so (by keeping it off your parking area,) the dog will continue to want to mark there. Generally a bit of dog pee doesn't harm anything though...

Comment: If that dog don't do it. Another one will come up. Actually more then one will come up. It is good to have one instead of more.

Answer (score 2):

Dogs tend to frequent certain spots to go potty, and nowhere else. Hopefully, this is just a minor issue and this post was geared towards increasing rep rather than trying a list of suggested ways to repel this dog from your parking area... So if nothing else works, before taking the hose to him (effective 100% of the time) , mix a little water in with some chili pepper flakes and apply to desired area a little while before the dogs usual potty break.  Dogs identify their toilet with the nose, and he'll soon find another area that he'll mark as his.